# Filling ArrayList vs LinkedList

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, performance-testing, microbenchmark

I have been thinking that `LinkedList` fills faster than `ArrayList`. As I know `ArrayList` is based on simple array with limited length(constant). So every time array is out of range, new array with higher range will be created. `LinkedList` is much simpler. It hasn't got any limit (except for memory), so it should be filled faster. But I run next code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int length = 7000000;

        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        long oldTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println("LinkedList fill: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - oldTime));

        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        oldTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println("ArrayList fill: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - oldTime));
    }
```

The output is:

```
LinkedList fill: 3936
ArrayList fill: 628
```

Why so?

Comment: Because your benchmark is flawed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: Did you try to swap them? First the arraylist and than the linkedlist?

Comment: if you do vice versa i.e. ArrayList first and then LL? Also pass on the length to ArrayList constructor and see what happens?

Comment: Nothing changes. You could run them separately in two different programms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really benchmark performance like that in Java. See [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) for a more detailed explanations of the many things that can go wrong.

If I [test your code](https://bitbucket.org/assylias/performance/src/17e9f57bd95718ab7c64113abb9047925e9eb443/src/main/java/com/assylias/performance/SO26404256.java?at=master) with [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) I get the following results:

```
Benchmark                      Mode  Samples  Score   Error  Units
c.a.p.SO26404256.arrayList     avgt        5  7.661 ± 0.672  ms/op
c.a.p.SO26404256.linkedList    avgt        5  9.675 ± 1.213  ms/op
```

So filling a LinkedList seems to be slightly slower than filling an arrayList, but the difference is a lot less than your test indicated.

As for the reason for the difference, it is probably because each element of a LinkedList is wrapped in a `Node`: that means more object creations and more garbage collections. And the penalty due to array copies in ArrayList is probably less than you think because they are highly optimised.

Comment: All in one link by [Oracle Wiki](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/MicroBenchmarks). See Relevant links too..